# Doesn't recognize flutter image

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I am trying to add an image like this -

```
 Tabs('Books', Image.asset('assets/image/health.png'), 2),
```

Here is my complete tab widget

```
Widget Tabs(String header, Image iconName, int index) {
    return Tab(
      height: 90,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: 71,
            height: 71,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: _selected[index] == true
                    ? configColors.orange
                    : Colors.white,
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                  spreadRadius: 2,
                  blurRadius: 7,
                  offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                ),
              ],),
            child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Image.asset('$iconName',
                    color: _selected[index] == true
                        ? Colors.white
                        : configColors.grey)),
          ),
          FittedBox(
            child: Text(
              header,
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: "Mark-Pro",
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                  fontSize: 15),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

use -  `icon: Image.asset('$iconName')`

pubspec.yamal - [image: pubspec.yamal]

error - `Unable to load asset: Image(image: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/image/phone.png"), frameBuilder: null, loadingBuilder: null, alignment: Alignment.center, this.excludeFromSemantics: false, filterQuality: low)`

url - [image: assets]

***I tried putting an image I used elsewhere and it doesn't work either***
In my opinion, it's not about the path, but about the display method. If you know, please tell a newbie

Comment: do you have assets folder in project root path?

Comment: Is the path you set in `pubspec.yaml` the same as the actual image asset path?

Comment: @eamirho3ein 
i added more description

Comment: @Jungwon i added more description

Comment: Are you using flutter web?

Comment: @eamirho3ein no

Comment: dont import all the images path in pub file ..just give the path where you have images Like that
 assets:
    - assets/images/

Comment: What logs do I get when I run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` ?

Comment: @Nagual This didn't solve the problem. And other images that are outside the tabbar, they work (see addendum to the question (below))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here you are trying to add an Image Widget inside another Image Widget.
you need to change `iconName` to be just a noraml String not a Widget, so the parameters will be like this

> - `Tabs('Books', "assets/image/health.png", 2)`
> - `Widget Tabs(String header, String iconName, int index)`

so your Image Widget now will take a String

```
IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Image.asset('$iconName',
                color: _selected[index] == true
                    ? Colors.white
                    : configColors.grey)),
      ),
```

- try this for better understanding: https://flutlab.io/editor/d9beff31-dd59-464a-8d31-77cd3bb79a25

hope I could help.

Answer (score 1):

change `iconName` type to `string` like this:

```
 Widget Tabs(String header, String iconName, int index) {// <-- there
        return Tab(
          height: 90,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 71,
                height: 71,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: _selected[index] == true
                        ? configColors.orange
                        : Colors.white,
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                      spreadRadius: 2,
                      blurRadius: 7,
                      offset: Offset(0, 3), // changes position of shadow
                    ),
                  ],),
                child: IconButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    icon: Image.asset('$iconName',
                        color: _selected[index] == true
                            ? Colors.white
                            : configColors.grey)),
              ),
              FittedBox(
                child: Text(
                  header,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontFamily: "Mark-Pro",
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      fontSize: 15),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
```

then call it like this:

```
Tabs('Books', 'assets/image/health.png', 2),
```

Comment: It was the first thing I tried

Comment: Did not help(((

Comment: just assets/image/health.png have this issue? not other ?

Comment: All the ones I added last. They are highlighted in green in the screenshot (books, computer, phone, health)

Answer (score 0):

[image]
***pubspec.yaml***

```
assets:
    - assets/images/
```

I don't know how your `Tab()` method is implemented, but when implemented as `Tab Widget`, it runs normally.

```
Tab(
            height: 200,
            text: "header",
            icon: Image.asset('assets/images/image1.jpg'),
          ),
```

Check that the spacing of the code that sets the `assets` path in `pubspec.yaml` is not wrong!

Comment: I can provide a screenshot where you can clearly see that other images are displayed correctly!

Answer (score -1):

Iconame can't be type Image. Change to String and change

```html
 Tabs('Books', Image.asset('assets/image/health.png'), 2),
```

to

```html
 Tabs('Books', "assets/image/health.png", 2),
```

Comment: The String argument type cannot be assigned to the Image parameter type. I get an error

Comment: It is not normal. The name of the image of type String is even its main argument

Comment: I can't argue with you. But the problem remains valid :(

Comment: Try `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get`, close and reopen your editor or restart your computer lol

Comment: Apparently this is my last chance

Comment: Try it and get back to me

Comment: It did not help :(